# How to make Google Images display results in an "inline frame"?

Tags: google-image-search

Sometimes, Google Images results are shown in an "inline frame": when you click a picture from the results, it pops a black frame with preview, link to image, link to page and related image, as in the screenshot below:

[image: Google images with "inline frame"]

But sometimes images in results only link to the direct image (ie clicking on an image just sends you to the image URL).

The exact same URL behaves differently on two browser, and the behavior is not consistent on the same browser, so I suspect there's a setting somewhere but I cannot find any.

Any clue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on the version of Google you use.

If you use google.com, images will be shown in the inline frame you mention.

If you use google.fr or google.de for example, images will be shown loaded in a frame with the page that the image appears on in the background.

Comment: That was it indeed. Thanks! Still not sure why depending on the user logged in Google redirects to dot com or dot "your region", but I found a Firefox extension to always pick dot com.

Answer (score -2):

Try This
http://google.com/images/work.jpg" alt = "Vote Me" title = "Images" >

Comment: It's not clear how to try your proposal.